Landlord Violation?
Alice paid their landlord for the last two and a half years up front for rent.
Alice recently had had some financial hardship.
Alice contacted the landlord Larry and advised him about her financial hardships because of medical issues and advised him she would have a hard time paying the rent for the next 4 months on time.
Larry agreed to take partial payments until paid in full.
This last month Alice made a 400 dollar payment so far. Larry contacted Alice on Thursday wanting to know how much she would be paying. Alice advised him that she's not sure and that it may have to be on Saturday. Saturday came and Alice did not get the pay that she was anticipating so she contacted Larry that evening and explained to him that she did not get her pay and now she will not receive it till Monday to apologize if that was a problem.
Larry posted a 3-day notice on her door on Sunday and also came to the property and entered the back fenced-in yard which Alice had a back slider door open.
Is it legal for a landlord to enter a back fenced in yard and look through a tennants back open door, posting a 3-day notice on a Sunday after already taking partial payment for the month?
Are there any laws protecting renters when they cannot pay in full?

If she paid 2.5 years upfront, a foolish financial choice, why would she owe rent in the next four months?  If she paid nothing, she would still have 2 years and 2 months to not pay anything.

@PeteB. That was for the last 2.5 years. The detail seems rather irrelevant except to establish that Alice is otherwise current on her rent.

@NuclearHoagie I think it is meant to show a pattern of paying in full in on time for rent, not that she is current and doesn't owe anything.

In general, to vary a contract you need a new contract
Alice must pay the rent. If Alice does not pay the rent, Larry can choose to exercise his rights (to eviction among other things) or not. He can choose to let one go, or two, or three, or four, but he always has the right to start exercising his rights.
Larry’s agreement to take partial payments is not an enforceable contract because Alice did not provide any consideration for it. Alice needed to offer something of value - paying a partial sum on Tuesday instead of the full sum on Wednesday would be enough - but it appears that nothing of value was offered. So, Larry can change his mind; his forbearance in not exercising his rights is a gift, and he can decide to stop being generous.
For example, many, many years ago during the Great Depression, my great-grandfather was unable to pay the rent. The landlord, perhaps knowing that they were unlikely to find another tenant, agreed that he could stay in return for maintaining the property. That’s a binding contract - the labour of maintenance was something of value.
There are legal principles such as waiver and estoppel that may prevent Larry from changing his mind about conduct in the past or regarding any specific promises he made that Alice relied upon. But, in general, at any point in time, conduct in the future by both parties must meet their obligations under the contract.
A landlord exercising their rights, such as posting an eviction notice, does not commit trespass.

Depending upon the terms of the oral modification agreed to by the landlord, I would think that there would be some sort of estoppel against evicting while it was in effect. Not all jurisdictions require consideration for a modification of a contract (indeed, I wouldn't be surprised if the requirement of consideration to modify is no longer a majority rule).

In some US states, accepting partial payment makes eviction impossible. So accepting $400 partial rent and then posting a 3-days notice may in fact be illegal. I'm not sure if that's the case in Florida, but it would be in some of the US states. Actually, it seems like in Florida it is allowed to post 3-days notice even after accepting a partial payment.

florida
In Florida, it is permissible for a landlord to accept partial payment and then post a 3-days notice. See Section 83.54:

If the tenant fails to pay rent when due and the default continues for 3 days, excluding Saturday, Sunday, and legal holidays, after delivery of written demand by the landlord for payment of the rent or possession of the premises, the landlord may terminate the rental agreement.

and then:

However, a landlord does not waive the right to terminate the rental agreement or to bring a civil action for that noncompliance by accepting partial rent for the period

That basically specifically allows the situation described between Alice and Larry. That would not be true in every US state - some do in fact have contrary precedents (e.g.: the neighboring Georgia, where the practical application of that ruling is that a partial payment defers eviction).
The situation is slightly different if Larry accepts a partial payment after posting the notice:

If partial rent is accepted after posting the notice for nonpayment, the landlord must:
1. Provide the tenant with a receipt stating the date and amount received and the agreed upon date and balance of rent due before filing an action for possession;
2. Place the amount of partial rent accepted from the tenant in the registry of the court upon filing the action for possession; or
3. Post a new 3-day notice reflecting the new amount due.

